# Why does MySQL throw a debug error?

Tags: mysql

I was trying to run a MySQL query where I am supposed to bypass (/UNION SELECT/). I think I did it right, however, it now shows me a debug message saying that the used SELECT statements have a different number of columns.
I don't get what would be wrong with this since I want to have all columns joined.
I used:

```
SELECT id, 
       phone_number, 
       last_name 
FROM patients 
WHERE last_name LIKE '' UNION/**/SELECT med_bills FROM patients;#'
```

Now the last '-sign I did not include in my own query but it is shown in the debug message.
What did I do wrong here?

Comment: What does "*bypass (/UNION SELECT/)*" mean? You can't use a `UNION` clause when the columns in the `SELECT` list on both sides are different in quantity and / or data types.

Comment: You probably want a `JOIN`, not a `UNION`.  Please provide info on what is the tables and what you want in the output.